# JQuery click event not working properly with an <i> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<button type="button" class="add-to-cart"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>cumpara</button>
                <button class="added add-to-cart"><i class="material-icons check">check</i><i class="material-icons clear">clear</i>Adaugat in cos</button>
```

I have these two buttons with this CSS code:

```
.add-to-cart
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: em(48);
    background: complement($rodie);
    border: none;
    color: $gray-100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: em(48);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: em(18);
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 250ms ease-out;
    &.clicked
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    &:hover
    {
        background: complement(darken($rodie, 10%));
    }
    i
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        font-size: em(18);
        height: em(48);
        width: em(48);
        line-height: em(44);
    }
}

.added
{
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    top: 90%;
    z-index: 22;
    background: $verde-jungla;
    &:hover
    {
        background: $verde-jungla;
    }
    &.clicked
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .check
    {
        left: 0;
    }
}

.clear
{
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    height: em(48);
    width: em(48);
    right: 0;
    background: desaturate(red, 30%);
    &:hover
    {
        background: desaturate(darken(red, 10%), 30%);
    }
}
```

I want the button to respond to a click event by transitioning the second button, which has an icon and a message (that informs the user that the product has been added to the cart) attached to it. The first transition works. When I click on the button, the other one appears as it's supposed to, but when the clear "button" (the `<i>` with the class of clear) is pressed, it's not working.

This is the JQuery code:

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
  $('.add-to-cart').addClass("clicked");
});

$('.clear').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
  $('.add-to-cart').removeClass("clicked");
});
```

Keep in mind that if I change the selected element of the second click event, the process works just fine.

Comment: This is not css, this is sass, it will not run in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the `.clear` button inside an `.add-to-cart` is asking for problems.
When you click `.clear`, at the same time you click `.add-to-cart`.

You did add `event.preventDefault`, but you don't just want to prevent the default. You also need to prevent the event from "bubbling" up.
Also, the variable `event` does not exist, you need to add it as the name of the first argument.

Try:

```
$('.clear').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();// Stop bubbling up
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.add-to-cart').removeClass("clicked");
});
```

But a far better solution would be to move `.clear` outside of the button that has `.add-to-car`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <button type="button" class="add-to-cart"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>cumpara</button>
   <button class="added add-to-cart"><i class="material-icons check">check</i><i class="material-icons clear" style=" padding: 0 10px;">clear</i>Adaugat in cos</button>




 $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
   $('.add-to-cart').addClass("clicked");
 });

 $('.clear').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.add-to-cart').removeClass("clicked");
 });
```